# setFindTimeout and pollUntil with Intern for elements that are not visible on initial page load

Tags: javascript, intern

I'm having an issue getting Intern 2 to wait for elements to be present. In Intern 1 I was using  `wait()`to set express time periods for the page to wait for an element to be present after some user action. With Intern 2 there seems to be `setFindTimeout()` which should always tell a `find()` method to wait a bit for the element to be present. I've set `setFindTimeout()` and tried using `pollUntil` to handle these waits but the tests are still failing with the error "element not visible".

Here is a sample test that is using the same requirements as my real tests and is looking for an element Id which appears 5 seconds after this [page](http://kgstew.com/waittest.html) loads.

```
define([
'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'require',
'tests/util',
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/Command',
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/Session',
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, util, Command, Session, pollUntil) {

registerSuite([   
    {
        name: 'testing_find_by_wait',

        test_create_form_on_web: function() {
            console.log('Create a form with account, number, number and formula fields')

            return this.remote
                .setFindTimeout(10000)
                .setWindowSize(1280, 960)
                .get("http://www.kgstew.com/waittest.html")
                .then(pollUntil('return document.getElementById("demo")', 10000))
                .findById('demo')
                    .click()
                    .end()

        }
    }
]);
});
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get, and from which line?

Comment: Error is "ElementNotVisible: [POST http://10.0.1.34:4444/wd/hub/session/204fe805-74f6-401d-a22f-5afd976b547c/element/9/click] element not visible" on line 29

Comment: When the test runs it does not appear that it is waiting for at least 10 seconds before it determines that the element is not visible. My understanding is that this is what `setFindTimeout()` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you C Snover for your help getting this worked out.

I was misunderstanding how `setFindTimeout()` and `pollUntil` were working. They both look for elements to be present in the DOM (which they were) but if the element is not visible (ie style is `display:none`) when a `click()` command is issued, the test will fail.

What we wanted to do is wait for the element to be present after some kind of user action. Got the idea from C Snover to watch the `element.offsetWidth` for it to be greater than 0.

We created the following utility in our testing suite.

```
element_visible_by_class: function(elem) {
    return function(elem) {
        elem = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
        if (!elem || elem.length == 0) { return null; }
        elem = elem[0];
        return (elem.offsetWidth > 0 && elem.offsetHeight > 0) ? elem : null;
     }  
},
```

Now from any test we can call `.then(pollUntil(util.element_visible_by_class(), ['class_name'], 10000))` and it will wait until that element is visible on the page.

Answer (score 2):

The element is being discovered just fine. Per the error, it is failing to `click` on the element. This is happening because the element is empty and has no style so it is zero size and cannot be clicked at the time you are trying to click on it. You need to wait for the element to exist and be visible before you can try to click on it.

Comment: I agree and I have used `setFindTimeout()` as well as the `pollUntil` helper to try to achieve this wait rather than setting an explicit `sleep()`. My understanding is that `setFindTimeout` should set the amount of time that any `find()` method should wait before moving on. Am I not using these wait methods and helpers correctly?

Comment: Does this mean the web app should be modified to set some window properties when the async calls finished so that these properties can be polled with pollUntil in intern?